# How to set property eclipse.update.reconcile=true in Eclipse product built with Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho, e4

I build my Eclipse 4 Application with Maven Tycho 0.15.0. Everything works fine except of the fact, that when i add

```
<configurations>
...
<property name="org.eclipse.update.reconcile" value="true" />
</configurations>
```

Tycho is ignoring the property and writing org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false to the config.ini.

I want my application to use every bundle that I drop in the plugins folder therefore I added org.eclipse.update.configurator and the above property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As described on [official site](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_p2_configuringproducts.htm):

> When setting the start level for org.eclipse.update.configurator,
>   PDE/Build will also automatically set In addition to these properties,
>   org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false.

In fact if you point

```
<plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator"/>
```

in .product file you always have default start level as a result

```
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
```

in your config.ini file.

Solution is not specify

```
<plugin id="org.eclipse.update.configurator"/>
```

in .product file. It still will be in plugins.